# Regexp for 2 date formats SED

Tags: regular-expression, sed, awk

How could I write a regular expression for sed which extracts only the DATE field from log files accepting both of these date formats:

```
Jun  9 16:56:14 mailserver postfix ...
2017-06-04T06:59:36.984086+02:00 mailserver postfix ...
```

With awk printing the $1 column would work in the second case but not in the first.

Comment: Do you really mean you want just the date field, or did you want the date and time? (Your `awk` example would provide the datetime stamp, not just the date.)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$ cat test.txt 
Jun  9 16:56:14 mailserver postfix ...
2017-06-04T06:59:36.984086+02:00 mailserver postfix ...
$ sed 's/^\([0-9:+\.T\-]*\|[A-Z][a-z]*\s*[0-9]*\s[0-9:]*\)\s.*/\1/' < test.txt 
Jun  9 16:56:14
2017-06-04T06:59:36.984086+02:00
```

Explanation:

- Match on the beginning of line: `^`
- use backslashed parentheses to have your area of interest for the back reference in the substitution (see below), i.e. “the date” before “the rest of the log text”
- in the parentheses: match both variants (use `\|` to denote the alternative of both sub-expressions)
- after the parentheses: match the rest of the line, because we want to throw it away (it seems a bit counter intuitive at first, but see next point)
- replace *the whole line* (that is why we match the rest) with the back reference to the date matching: `\1`

Comment: @roaima
I can certainly do that, however the question indicates, that `awk '{print $1}'` gives the expected answer for the second case, which is: `2017-06-04T06:59:36.984086+02:00`